# Не видит axios vue + Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

где ошибся? в консоле пишет

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: axios is not defined"

found in

---> <OffersList> at resources/assets/js/components/OffersList.vue
       <Root>
```

и еще такая ошибка

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
```

файл app.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

import axios from 'axios';


Vue.component('offers-list', require('./components/OffersList.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

сам компонент

```
<template>
    <div class="offers">
        <div class="offer" v-for="offeri in listoffers">
            <img src="img/com-user.png" alt="" class="avatar">
            <div class="data-offer">
                <div class="card">
                    <a href="/offers/" class="text">{{offeri.title}}</a>
                    <p class="fullname">nadinak [Nadinak]</p>
                </div>
                <div class="data-offer-meta">
                    <span class="date">09.03.2019г. 15:15</span>
                    <div class="data-action">
                        <p class="up">
                            <svg class="up"><use xlink:href="#up"></use></svg>
                            <span>1</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="down">
                            <svg class="up"><use xlink:href="#up"></use></svg>
                            <span>1</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="comments">
                            <svg class="comment"><use xlink:href="#comment"></use></svg>
                            <span>0</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function(){
          return {
              listoffers: []
          }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.update()
        },
        methods: {
            update: function () {

                axios.get('/offers/list').then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data)
                    this.listoffers = response.data
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: если поместить import axios from 'axios'; в компонент то axios работает, но вторая ошибка не исчезает и можно ли подключить axios для всех компонентов?

Comment: он же подключён по-умолчанию. смотри `bootstrap.js`, который подключается в `app.js`